# Depth Estimation Algorithms without Reference Image in Computer Vision for Webcam Captured Video Data of a Person

Tags: computer-vision, distance, parameter-estimation

I am currently working on a computer vision project that involves analyzing video data of a person captured from a webcam. In this project, I need to compute the depth map or distance of a specific object (in my case, the nose of the person) from the camera. Unfortunately, I do not have access to any reference image with known depth or distance information for calibration purposes.

Considering the constraints of working with webcam-captured video data and the absence of reference images, are there any known or solved algorithms/methods that can help me achieve accurate depth estimation? I would greatly appreciate any insights, resources, or techniques that can be employed to estimate the depth or distance of the person from the webcam without the need for a reference image. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at *monocular depth estimation* methods that only require a single image instead of a stereo pair. In particular, [this](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Godard_Unsupervised_Monocular_Depth_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf) approach can estimate depth without ground-truth depth maps making it unsupervised and easier to develop/train.

You can also start from a pretrained depth model, and then fine-tune on your webcam images.

Comment: What are some good pre-trained models for this purpose? Are there specific methods for capturing depth of "faces" in images?